# Is this file a virus? It's jQuery and turned up in clam TK as a threat

Tags: 12.04, scripts

Does anyone know what this is and how to remove it, because it keeps turning up everytime I remove it with clam TK.

I have only added a part of the file because it it superbig.  Just want to know how to prevent it from coming back. And what the hell it is.

> /*! jQuery v1.7.2 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
>   (function(a,b){function cy(a){return
>   f.isWindow(a)?a:a.nodeType===9?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}function
>   cu(a){if(!cj[a]){var
>   b=c.body,d=f("<"+a+">").appendTo(b),e=d.css("display");d.remove();if(e==="none"||e===""){ck||(ck=c.createElement("iframe"),ck.frameBorder=ck.width=ck.height=0),b.appendChild(ck);if(!cl||!ck.createElement)cl=(ck.contentWindow||ck.contentDocument).document,cl.write((f.support.boxModel?"":"")+""),cl.close();d=cl.createElement(a),cl.body.appendChild(d),e=f.css(d,"display"),b.removeChild(ck)}cj[a]=e}return
>   cj[a]}function ct(a,b){var
>   c={};f.each(cp.concat.apply([],cp.slice(0,b)),function(){c[this]=a});return
>   c}function cs(){cq=b}function cr(){setTimeout(cs,0);return
>   cq=f.now()}function ci(){try{return new
>   a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}}function
>   ch(){try{return new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){}}function
>   cb(a,c){a.dataFilter&&(c=a.dataFilter(c,a.dataType));var
>   d=a.dataTypes,e={},g,h,i=d.length,j,k=d[0],l,m,n,o,p;for(g=1;g")k=l;else
>   if(l!=="*"&&l!==k){m=l+" "+k,n=e[m]||e["* "+k];if(!n){p=b;for(o in
>   e){j=o.split(" ");if(j[0]===l||j[0]===""){p=e[j[1]+"
>   "+k];if(p){o=e[o],o===!0?n=p:p===!0&&(n=o);break}}}}!n&&!p&&f.error("No conversion from "+m.replace(" "," to
>   ")),n!==!0&&(c=n?n(c):p(o(c)))}}return c}function ca(a,c,d){var
>   e=a.contents,f=a.dataTypes,g=a.responseFields,h,i,j,k;for(i in g)i in
>   d&&(c[g[i]]=d[i]);while(f[0]==="*")f.shift(),h===b&&(h=a.mimeType||c.getResponseHeader("content-type"));if(h)for(i
>   in e)if(e[i]&&e[i].test(h)){f.unshift(i);break}if(f[0]in
>   d)j=f[0];else{for(i in d){if(!f[0]||a.converters[i+"
>   "+f[0]]){j=i;break}k||(k=i)}j=j||k}if(j){j!==

I hope someone can help.

thank you,
Laura

Comment: Can you specify where exactly the file is found. Looks like a false positive, but if someone whats to look at the source, here it is: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/106681

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is a script used by many different sites to make interactive web sites. You can find more information here:

http://jquery.com/

To make the file smaller, the script has been "minified". This means that there are no spaces, and each variable has been reduced to a single letter. It also means that it is not easy for a human to read the script, so it might look dubious to you.

If you browse the web much, you will soon encounter a new site that downloads this file again. If you just leave it where it is, your browser won't need to download it again each time a new site wants to use it.

Cheers,

James